# processing undefined properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

Can i add some functional to the object, which will return default value when accessing a undefined object property?

For example something like this:

```
var obj = {
    a:1,
    b:2,
    // can i add some functional here, which 
    // will return default value 
    // when accessing a missing property 
    // for example "property "+prop+" missing in obj"?
}
alert(obj.c) // "property c missing in obj"
```

is it any way to do it?

Comment: Dude... I think you're going WAY out of your way to set custom getters and setters and handlers for some non-standard data. Are you writing this for some client-side functionality, or is this some SSJS?

Answer (score 0):

What you want are JavaScript [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). However, browser support for them is weak.

If you expect your program to run on all modern browsers, you shouldn't use proxies; however, if you're using JavaScript server-side or in an otherwise constricted environment, it is an option. I think that Node.js, for example, supports them (although I could be wrong on this).

If you *are* working on cross-browser code, then I do not know of any neat way to implement the functionality you want.

Comment: i need it for proxying some objects for make it available from web workers by postMessage all properties of this object to the same object in main script, for example console

Comment: no, i am working only on the webkit browsers, because i create a complex product, which also contains hardware - server rack, networking and client workstations with linux based workspace.
it is not a public web project, so i need it feature in isolated web environment for optimize client side evristic by using web workers.
my web frontend use a lot of javascript frameworks like OpenLayers, extjs, and others, and work with a lot of datastreams between clients and many different servers like billing info, gps monitoring data, video streaming, etc.

Comment: in several cases web interface will stuck, so i need to move a lot of code into parallel processes and in most cases i don`t know what global objects will be used in some code.
i don`t want write by self for example DOM implementation emulator with all DOM properties and methods, so i need to route missing parts to the main script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert((obj.c!=undefined)?obj.c:"Undefined");
```

To actually answer your question, you should never be looking for a property or method of an object that doesn't exist. If you happen to be looping through an objects properties you [] notation instead of dot notation such as.

```
var x, obj = {...}

for(x in obj){
  alert("Property name:"+x+" | value: "+obj[x]);
}
```

furthermore you can always wrap whatever statement that is questionable in a try/catch.

or function instead of object literal:

```
var obj = function(Params){
    this.URL = "";
    this.QueryString = new Array();
    this.Params = Params;
    this.Method = "POST";
    this.CallBack = "";
    this.OnSuccess = "";
    this.OnFailure = "";
    this.Header = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    this.Response = "";

    for(var Param in this.Params){
         switch (Param){
           case 'URL' : this.URL = this.Params[Param]; break;
           case 'QueryString' : this.QueryString = this.Params[Param];break;
           case 'Header' : this.Header = this.Params[Param]; break;
           case 'Method' : this.Method = this.Params[Param]; break;
           case 'CallBack': this.CallBack = this.Params[Param]; break;
           case 'OnSuccess': this.OnSuccess = this.Params[Param]; break;
           case 'OnFailure': this.OnFailure = this.Params[Param]; break;
               case default: something(); break; //I just don't have this line because I didn't need a default;
         }
    }

}
```

The above was the beginning to an ajax object I wrote, but you get the idea..

Comment: to Relic: no, i need a reflection proxy - test property availability inside obj - not external testing
this will be used for routing missing properties to the same named objects outside web worker by postMessage method

Comment: @elser So where are you going to call a property that may or may not be defined? are you generating properties and then not sure which ones are set? If I have more information there is probably a data solution with what you already have. If you're doing just one at a time you can use the conditional above: `if(obj.* === undefined){}`

Comment: I'm thinking maybe try setting your object as a function instead of an object literal... can we chat, I have some code you should look at

Comment: it should be something like [this](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies)

Comment: You'd have to wrap it in a conditional then, and see if the property exists before it asks for it in the loop. I don't think making a default action inside an object is a smooth way to solve what ever problem you've run into, but that's just me.